# Assign Global variable in access 2007 thru coding

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am having two forms `OrderForm` and `CustomerForm`.

In CustomerForm, I have a combo box, in which I select the orderId. If I click 'View' button , then it should show me a pop up which contains the order details of THIS 'orderId'

**CustomerForm**

- orderId stored in cbxOrderId
- viewOrderBut - button to display orderForm popup

I tried like below and failed

**viewOrderBut click event**

```
Forms![OrderForm].orderId = orderIdVar
```

*Error:*

Cannot find the referenced Form 'OrderForm'

my orderId variable in OrderForm is public

```
public orderId as string
```

Someone Please help me.

**Editing**

Code :

**CustomerForm :**

```
Public gblorderId as string



    Private Sub btnApproval_Click()
    gblOrderId = "123" 'static assignment of order id
    DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderForm"
    End Sub
```

**OrderForm**

```
Public orderId as string

Private Sub Form_Load()
orderId = gblOrderID
MsgBox("orderId="+orderId)
End sub
```

Error:

Prints...

orderId=

how to refer to CustomerForm.gblOrderId from OrderForm. I guess there i am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests that the form `OrderForm` cannot be found. Have you opened the form beforehand?

1. If `OrderForm` is a dialog form, then

This should be the code for your button :

```
orderIdVar = Forms!CustomerForm!comboBoxOrderId
docmd.openform "OrderForm"
```

and in the `Form_load` event of the OrderForm

```
me.orderId = orderIdVar
```

2.Otherwise

this :

```
docmd.openform "OrderForm"
Forms![OrderForm].orderId = orderIdVar
```

Comment: @sabari add more code please. When do you open the form? is it a dialog form? I need more details.

Comment: @sabari as you can see, your code is different from my answer. You must first open the form and then set the field. Unless the form has the modal property set to True. Then you need to do what I described in the first case.

Comment: Declare the global variable in Module is the perfect solution. worked.